# Blazor InputText suppress AutoCapitalize in Mobile Chrome version

Tags: blazor

I'm using Blazor with dotnet core 3.0 version.

When using InputText on my smartphone, there is always the first letter capital converted what is not wanted e.g. in case of email adresses etc.

Tried some of these things, but don't get it work until now to leave first char as entered by the user...

`<InputText 
                                                       @bind-Value="@CheckoutData.Email"
                                                       @attributes="autocapitalize=off"
                                                       AdditionalAttributes="autocapitalize","off" />`

Has anyone some idea or tip how to solve this by setting some property or something like this?

Thx!

Comment: [autocapitalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autocapitalize) : "The autocapitalize attribute never causes autocapitalization to be enabled for an <input> element with a type attribute whose value is url, email, or password" .  So why not add a `type="email"` attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

Give this page a read:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode

I don't think the InputText component allows you to set type="email" as it's probably setting it to text.

You can try adding this attribute:  inputmode="email" and let hope this works.  Worst case, don't use the InputText and just use the HTML input and then set type="email"

Comment: `InputText` support any `<input` tags attributes